# Where can I find the paper "Life cycle sustainability assessment (LCSA) for products and processes."

Tags: life-cycle-analysis

I am currently studying circular economy theory.  More specifically life cycle sustainability assessment theory. And I notice that a paper in this area that presents a lot of citations is

> Finkbeiner, M., K. Reimann, and R. Ackermann. 2008. *Life cycle*
> *sustainability assessment (LCSA) for products and processes.* Paper
> presented at SETAC Europe 18th Annual Meeting, 25–29 May 2008, Warsaw,
> Poland.

I trying to find this paper through the internet (in order to buy or download it, I don't know the current availability policy for this paper). But I was not even able to find the DOI code of this paper.

Can anyone help me to find how I can read such paper?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! The article is indeed hard to find, so I would suggest to ask either the conference organization or the authors. Contact information of SETAC is [here](https://dublin.setac.org/contact-us/staff-contacts/)
The authors work(ed) at the Sustainable Engineering group of the Institute of Environmental Technology, Technische Universität Berlin and for 2 their email addresses are listed [here](https://www.see.tu-berlin.de/menue/about_us_team/parameter/en/).